# Javascript variables are disappearing

Tags: javascript, variables

The page I'm working with is here:

http://harrisonfjord.com/survey/index.html

When you click on an object in each step, the "alt" tag of the image map region on which you clicked is being saved as a variable answer(current question number).

The code is here (ignore the comments, I've just put them in so I know what the hell I'm doing!):

```
$(window).load(function(){

        //#shape functions
        $('#shape area').hover(
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('hover');
            },
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).removeClass('hover');
            } //.hover allows 2 function - first is mouse on, second is mouse off
        ); //End #shape .hover function

        $('#shape area').click( //.click only allows 1 function.
            function(e){
                $('img.selected-region').removeClass('selected-region');
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('selected-region');
                var answer1 = $(this).attr("alt");
                alert(answer1);

            }
        );//End #Shape .click function



        //#height functions

        $('#height area').hover(
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('hover');
            },
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).removeClass('hover');
            }
        ); //End #height .hover function

        $('#height area').click(
            function(e){
                $('img.selected-region').removeClass('selected-region');
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('selected-region');
                var answer2 = $(this).attr("alt");
                alert(answer2 + answer1);

            }
        );//End #height .click function



        //#world functions
        $('#world area').hover(
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('hover');
            },
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).removeClass('hover');
            } 
        ); //End #world .hover function

        $('#world area').click(
            function(e){
                $('img.selected-region').removeClass('selected-region');
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('selected-region');
                var answer3 = $(this).attr("alt");
                alert(answer3);

            }
        );//End #world .click function           

    }); //End (window) onLoad function
```

As you can see, I'm creating an alert for each variable just so I can see that it's working when I click. However, after I press "next", the variable seems to erase itself. As you can see, in the second step, I'm alerting (answer1 + answer2), yet nothing comes up. Further, if you check the html code for "step 4", you'll see that instead of images I'm running a simple document.write script:

```
<h3>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(answer1);
    </script>
</h3>
```

yet, again, nothing displays. Why are my variables not persisting through the whole jquery survey?

Excuse the massive code below, but it might help resolve the issue - the entire .js code that runs the jquery survey steps, as well as the hover/click functions of each map.

```
(function($){

$(window).load(function(){

        //#shape functions
        $('#shape area').hover(
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('hover');
            },
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).removeClass('hover');
            } //.hover allows 2 function - first is mouse on, second is mouse off
        ); //End #shape .hover function

        $('#shape area').click( //.click only allows 1 function.
            function(e){
                $('img.selected-region').removeClass('selected-region');
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('selected-region');
                var answer1 = $(this).attr("alt");
                alert(answer1);

            }
        );//End #Shape .click function



        //#height functions

        $('#height area').hover(
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('hover');
            },
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).removeClass('hover');
            }
        ); //End #height .hover function

        $('#height area').click(
            function(e){
                $('img.selected-region').removeClass('selected-region');
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('selected-region');
                var answer2 = $(this).attr("alt");
                alert(answer2 + answer1);

            }
        );//End #height .click function



        //#world functions
        $('#world area').hover(
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('hover');
            },
            function(e){
                $('#'+ this.alt).removeClass('hover');
            } 
        ); //End #world .hover function

        $('#world area').click(
            function(e){
                $('img.selected-region').removeClass('selected-region');
                $('#'+ this.alt).addClass('selected-region');
                var answer3 = $(this).attr("alt");
                alert(answer3);

            }
        );//End #world .click function              

                // jQuery.extend merges contents of two or 
                // more objects together into the first object
                //$.extend(useranswers,{ 
                    //answer1 : $("img.selected-region").attr('rel') 
                //});

                //$.cookie('survery', 
                    //JSON.stringify(useranswers),
                    //{ expires: 7, path: '/', domain: '<your_domain_name>' }
                //);


    }); //End (window) onLoad function  

$.fn.smartWizard = function(options) {
        var defaults = {
              selectedStep: 0,  // Selected Step, 0 = first step
              errorSteps:[],    // Array Steps with errors
              enableAll:false,  // Enable All Steps, true/false
              animation:true,   // Animation Effect on navigation, true/false         
              validatorFunc:function(){return true;} // Step validation function, Step index will be passed
        };
        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);  

        return this.each(function() {
                obj = $(this); 
                var wizcurrent = 0;
                  var steps = $("ul > li > a", obj);
                  // Apply Default Style to Steps
                  applyCSS($(steps, obj),"wiz-anc-default");
                  // Hide All Steps on load
                hideAllSteps();

                $(steps, obj).bind("click", function(e){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var isDone = $(this, obj).attr("isDone");
                    if(isDone == 1){
                        var selIdx = steps.index(this);  
                        applyCSS($(wizcurrent, obj),"wiz-anc-done"); 
                        selectStep(selIdx);
                    }
                });
                // activates steps up to the selected step
                for(i=0;i<steps.length;i++){
                  if(i<=options.selectedStep || options.enableAll==true){
                    activateStep(i);
                  }
                }
                // highlight steps with errors
                $.each(options.errorSteps, function(i, n){
                  //applyCSS(steps.eq(n),"wiz-anc-error");
                  setErrorStep(n)
                });

                  selectStep(options.selectedStep);
                //Next Navigation
                $(".next", obj).bind("click", function(e){
                  e.preventDefault();  
                  var curStepIdx = $(steps, obj).index(wizcurrent);
                  if(options.validatorFunc(curStepIdx)){
                      var nextStepIdx = curStepIdx+1;
                      applyCSS($(wizcurrent, obj),"wiz-anc-done"); 
                      selectStep(nextStepIdx);
                  }
                });

                //Back Navigation
                $(".back", obj).bind("click", function(e){
                  e.preventDefault(); 
                  applyCSS($(wizcurrent, obj),"wiz-anc-done"); 
                  var prevIdx = $(steps, obj).index(wizcurrent)-1;
                  selectStep(prevIdx);
                });

                function selectStep(idx){
                    if(idx < steps.length && idx >= 0){
                      var selStepAnchor = $(steps, obj).eq(idx);
                      var selStepIdx =selStepAnchor.attr("href");
                      hideAllSteps();          
                      selStepAnchor.attr("isDone","1");

                      if(options.animation==true){
                        $(selStepIdx, obj).fadeIn("fast");
                      }else{
                        $(selStepIdx, obj).show();
                      }
                      applyCSS($(selStepAnchor, obj),"wiz-anc-current");
                      wizcurrent = selStepAnchor;
                    }
                }

                function activateStep(idx){
                    var selStepAnchor = steps.eq(idx);
                    selStepAnchor.attr("isDone","1");
                    applyCSS($(selStepAnchor, obj),"wiz-anc-done");
                }

                function setErrorStep(idx){
                    var selStepAnchor = steps.eq(idx);
                    selStepAnchor.attr("isError","1"); 
                    $(selStepAnchor, obj).addClass("wiz-anc-error"); 
                }

                function unsetErrorStep(idx){
                    var selStepAnchor = steps.eq(idx);
                    selStepAnchor.attr("isError",""); 
                    $(selStepAnchor, obj).removeClass("wiz-anc-error"); 
                } 

                function hideAllSteps(){
                    $(steps, obj).each(function(){
                        $($(this, obj).attr("href"), obj).hide();
                  });
                }

                function applyCSS(elm,css){
                    $(elm, obj).removeClass("wiz-anc-default");
                    $(elm, obj).removeClass("wiz-anc-current");
                    $(elm, obj).removeClass("wiz-anc-done");
                    $(elm, obj).addClass(css); 
                }
        });  
    };  
})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are defining the variables "var answer1" within a function, they're only defined in the scope of this function. Try this:

```
$(window).load(function(){

    var answer1, answer2, answer3;

    //#shape functions
    $('#shape area').hover(
    ...
```

Then loose the "var" within your click event functions.

Comment: Ahh fantastic, that solves the issue of alert(answer2 + answer1) not showing up when you click in step 2. However, the document.write(answer1) script (in step 4, after you click the world map) still isn't working. I tried adding the var declaration to just after the (function($){, and that didn't work either..

Comment: Try using jQuery's html() or text() function instead of document.write within a JS tag, and call it only once the variable you want to print has been actually defined (in this case "answer1").

Comment: I don't follow, where would I use html() / text()? Instead of document.write()?

Comment: Once you have defined the variable in question — e.g after this: "answer1 = $(this).attr("alt"); $('h3').text(answer1);". (You might want to give h3 still an id or use a more specific selector, if you have more than one h3 tag on your page.)

Answer (score 1):

Initialize the answer1 and answer 2 variables outside any function at the beginning of the script. This way the functions will use global variables instead of local.

Basically, if you create a new variable inside a function it will be only available inside that specific function (local). If it has been created before, outside a function, it uses that variable (global). Google on "JavaScript local and global variables" for more info regarding this topic.

```
var answer1, answer;
```

In short, put that at the beginning of your script and change further references to:

```
answer = .... // hence, no var before the variable name
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Nearly got it! (see the comment on Polarblau's answer). If I put it at the very beginning of the .js file the document.write function now writes "undefined" (previously it wasn't writing anything at all)..

Comment: Like polarblau says, try using some onclick function or anything that writes the variable once it has been defined.

The document.write now writes the variables at the execution of the script (thus on page load), the variables answer1 and answer1 are only initialized then, not yet defined.

You could give both a default value, like an empty string: var answer1 = "", etc..